# What does Jest's "const mock = jest.fn();" really do?

Tags: unit-testing, jestjs, mocking

I found this mocking example floating around on a [tutorial page](https://medium.com/@rickhanlonii/understanding-jest-mocks-f0046c68e53c), but I find it confusing that this is used as an example so often.

```
test("mock return value", () => {
  const mock = jest.fn();
  mock.mockReturnValue("bar");

  expect(mock("foo")).toBe("bar");
  expect(mock).toHaveBeenCalledWith("foo");
});
```

Does `const mock = jest.fn();` ever connect to a real function that needs to be mocked? If so, how does it know which function to mock? What is the use case for a new and random `mock` like this?

Comment: You could use it to test a higher-order function. The passed function should be given a certain value, and should return a certain output for the given input.

Comment: It creates a test double of a function that records the calls made to to it and responds as instructed. There's no actual implementation involved, as you can see by the fact that `mock` is the only thing referred to in the test (which is therefore pointless except by way of illustrating the available functionality).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example in this article only demonstrates the functionality of `jest.fn()`.  The `mock` object is not used by the code to be tested.

As it says, the mock function provides the below features:

- Capture calls
- Set return values
- Change the implementation

There is a scenario in real code where a function takes an object and calls a method on that object. In this scenario, you can create a mock object and pass it to that function.

E.g.

```js
// A real function need to be tested, it can be imported from a module
function getUserById(dbc, id) {
  return dbc.query('select * from users where id = $1;', [id]);
}

describe('70538368', () => {
  test('should pass', () => {
    const mDbc = {
      query: jest.fn().mockReturnValue({ name: 'teresa teng' }),
    };
    const actual = getUserById(mDbc, '1');
    expect(actual).toEqual({ name: 'teresa teng' });
    expect(mDbc.query).toBeCalledWith('select * from users where id = $1;', ['1']);
  });
});
```